# Sqlite UPDATE with PHP

Tags: php, sqlite

I currently have a php page that simply displays a DB. I want to be able to set a certain variable to 0.
I have tested using a select statement and it provides the correct data however the update does not seem to be working and I am unsure why. I have verified that all is correct by using the statement in DBbrowser and it works correctly.

```
$db = new PDO("sqlite:Checker.db");
$results = $db->query("UPDATE sites SET downs = '0' WHERE site = '$site'");
echo $site . " Downs cleared";
```

UPDATE:
Changed the code to as follows
'''
if (isset($_POST['clear'])) {

```
$site = $_POST['clear'];
$sql = "UPDATE sites SET downs = 0 WHERE site = :site";

try{
        $db = new PDO("sqlite:Checker.db");
    $results = $db->prepare($sql);
    $results->bindValue(':site', $site);
    $results->execute();
    if($results == FALSE)
        echo 'Not Cleared ' . $db->lastErrorMsg();
    else
        echo 'Cleared!';

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

It prints Cleared! however the DB is not updated

UPDATE 5/18/2020

Added the following piece for some error handling and got Execute Failed: ()

```
if (isset($_POST['clear'])) {

    $site = $_POST['clear'];
    $sql = "UPDATE sites SET downs = 0, time_down = NULL WHERE site = :site";

    try{
            $db = new PDO("sqlite:Checker.db");
        if (!($results = $db->prepare($sql))){
            echo "Prepare failed: (" . $db->errno . ") " . $db->error;
        }elseif (!$results->bindValue(':site', $site)){
            echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $results->errno . ") " . $results->error;
        }elseif (!$results->execute()) {
            echo "Execute failed: (" . $results->errno . ") " . $results->error;
        }else{
            $count = $results ->rowCount();
            if($results ->rowCount() == 0)
                echo 'Not Cleared ';
            else
                echo 'Cleared!';
        }

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

}
```

Comment: Are you getting any PHP or SQL errors?

Comment: No errors that I see no

Comment: It is in a try catch for PDO so it should catch something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After question edit:

Program is not giving all the feedback you need to troubleshoot this problem. This line `echo "Execute failed: (" . $results->errno . ") " . $results->error;`  giving this output `Execute Failed: ()` indicates that PHP Notices are not being reported. Check the [error reporting doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to see how to turn that on.

Once you are getting that feedback you will learn why this `. $results->errno . ") " . $results->error` is giving "Notice: Undefined property" messages. Review [PDO errorCode method doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorcode.php) and [PDO errorInfo doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php) for proper syntax and usage.

Once you know *why* the "Execute failed", you will be on the road to success!

---

(v1 answer)

This `($results == FALSE)` is unlikely to evaluate to true.  `$results` is the [return value from the `prepare` method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php#refsect1-pdo.prepare-returnvalues), i.e. a PDO Statement object.

It seems like you're trying to test the *result* of `$result->execute()` here `if($results == FALSE)`. The important thing to know is that an UPDATE is considered successful *even if it doesn't update any rows*.

You might try `if($results->rowCount() == 0)` ([doc here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)) instead.

(NB Despite the Note in the doc "*This method returns "0" (zero) with the SQLite driver at all times*", in my experience it produces accurate results for prepared UPDATE queries. That note could be old news;)

Comment: See my updates above if you still would like to help I'd appreciate it

Comment: Answer emended. Keep going.

Comment: Curious if you could point me in any direction I changed the error lines to ```echo "Execute failed: (" . $results->errorInfo() . ") " . $results->errorCode();``` and now get ```Execute failed: (Array) HY000```

Comment: review the errorInfo() doc again specifically the return value. You need to see the details.

Comment: Narrowed it down to a readonly db. Still trying to fix that but thank you for all the help!